# Given a query how to reduce the number of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do the following in rails 3:

```
@groups_active = Group.active_groups(current_user)
```

active_groups is a scope. This query works fine. I then want to do the following:

```
if @groups_active.count > 9
   @groups_active[0..10]
end
```

Meaning if there are more than 10 items in the @groups_active, take just the TOP 10, which thanks to the scope ordering are the most active.

Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is. You can limit the number of results from a query with `Model.your_scope.limit(10)`, and if it is a query that doesn't work with a SQL `LIMIT` then you can use `Model.your_scope.first(10)`. That's an `Array#first`, which accepts a fixnum argument to be used as expected…

Comment: I can't do that because I need to know first if there are more than 10, so if there are more than 10 I want to show a SEE ALL link. I can't do that if I do limit or first. Which is why I was thinking about doing the all, finding out the length and then truncating the object if needed so I don't hit the DB twice. Thoughts?

Comment: You should limit to 11 then and you can pop the last item off. This is pretty common — you're not doing anything unexpected or out-of-the-ordinary, despite it feeling a bit unclean.

Answer (score 0):

```
@groups_active = Group.active_groups(current_user).limit(10)
```

or you could add the `.limit(10)` part to your scope.

**Edited**

I would go with one limit(10) request and one count. It could be more effective then retrieving 20, 50, or more records and using only the first 10 of them.
But still, it requires testing and benchmarking.